# Centralizar mapa com mais de 1 (um) marcador

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Gostaria de uma ajudinha se possível.

Estou desenvolvendo um site, e implementando funções do Google Maps V3 Javascript, mas não encontrei em nenhuma documentação sobre como centralizar o mapa contendo 2 ou mais marcadores.

Não centralizar em 1 (um) marcador, mas centralizar nos marcadores por igual, aplicando o zoom automaticamente, etc...

Acho que deixei bem explicado, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço...

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Encontrei a resposta no link que o amigo luciorubeens deixou nos comentários...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719951/google-maps-api-v3-auto-center-map-with-multiple-markers

Comment: Mesma dúvida respondida no [SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719951/google-maps-api-v3-auto-center-map-with-multiple-markers), talvez lhe ajude

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de utilizar dois pontos ou mais, use o `LatLngBounds()` para centralizar o mapa.

**API-**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

**-js**

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.4555729, 9.169236),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        panControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), myOptions);



    var Item_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5983128, 8.9172776);

    var myPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4555729, 9.169236);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Item_1,
        map: map
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPlace,
        map: map
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(myPlace);
    bounds.extend(Item_1);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
initialize();
```

**-css**

```
#mapCanvas{width:500px;height:300px;}
```

**html -**

```
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

**VEJA FUNCIONANDO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/22qte/

Comment: Lollipop, tomei a liberdade de trazer o código do JSFiddle para cá, para evitar comprometer sua resposta caso o serviço fique offline. Você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/48672/revisions) a qualquer momento.

Comment: @rrnan, tentei executar, mas não consegui. E pra mim ainda está off.

Comment: Que estranho, aqui está funcionando normalmente: [Imagem](http://i.imgur.com/tmTwAQE.jpg).

Comment: amigos...  nao funciona...  o link correto para o  fiddle eh : VEJA FUNCIONANDO: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/22qte/